# How to display the a different time then the local server time using php date function?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I understand that < ? echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ? > will get me "Tuesday 18th of June 2013 10:45:32 PM" or date and local time of where my server is located each I believe, it's Texas.

I want to show California time or PDT each is 2 hours behind my server time.

I have tried to change the timezone with < ? date_default_timezone_set('PDT'); ? > but it didn't change the result.

Please note that I'm not trying to get the data from the user computer (we can do that with JS or other user side language). I want to get the time from the server minus 2 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example shows how to get the current time in another time zone.  The correct [IANA time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for US Pacific time is `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Refer also to the [PHP documentation on Date and Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Wikipedia has [a good reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to the available time zone identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

this function will return you the time according to the time Zone

```
function currenttime($y,$m,$d){
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimezone( $timezone );
        $y=$date->format($y);
        $m=$date->format($m);
        $d=$date->format($d);
        $h=$date->format('H');
        $i=$date->format('i');
        $s=$date->format('s');
            return mktime($h,$i,$s,$m,$d,$y);
    }
```

to get desired time zone use this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

Get timestamp using time().

Adjust timestamp to the timezone you want to display.

Then display it with date().

```
$ts = time() - (2*60*60); // minus 2 hours
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $ts);
```

You can fix timezone to UTC to avoid influence from server time zone setting.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Or just use gmdate() instead of date(), to display in UTC timezone.

```
$ts = time() - (2*60*60); // minus 2 hours
echo gmdate('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $ts);
```

Comment: Bad idea. This will actually change the time, rather than adjust it for the zone.  Also you are then very dependent on your server time zone settings and knowledge of time zone rules.  PHP can do this for you.

Answer (score -1):

This might give you an idea..

```
<?php
echo '2 hours behind my server time: '. date('Y-m-d h:m:i', strtotime('+2 hour')) ."\n";
?>
```

Comment: This just adds two hours to the output time when formatting.  It will not take any time zone rules into account.  And the OP said he ways *behind* by two hours anyway.

Comment: You ask: "I want to show California time or PDT each is 2 hours behind my server time", this code above SHOWS 2 hours behind the server time. ..and if you would like to SHOW the time from the server minus 2 hours you should write ('-2 hour')